# pandas recursive read_csv while adding column to each

Tags: python, pandas, generator

I'm recursively reading many csv's in multiple directories, and each time a read one in I want to add a column called `num` which is just the index of which csv it was in the list.

```
path = r'data/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "**/*.csv"), recursive=True)
```

After I have the filenames I want to read each in and then add the column, but leave it as a generator to simply `concat` afterwards. Is it possible to `enumerate` a generator?

```
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
df_from_each_file = (df.insert(0,'num',i,allow_duplicates=True) for i, df in enumerate(df_from_each_file))
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

This just returns a bunch of `None` df's

Comment: `df.insert()` does not return what you think it returns.

Comment: @Goyo even if it does the operation in-place it should still work the way it is, no?

Comment: In the second line you are asking for a bunch of `None`s  so that is what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) within the `generator` like:

```
path = r'data/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "**/*.csv"), recursive=True)

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f).assign(num=i) for i, f in enumerate(all_files))    
concatenated_df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```